# Basic Qt layout: Adding to a frame

Tags: qt, qt5

I am just staring Qt, so hopefully is a rookie question. Working in Qt Creator 2.7.2, Qt 5, standard desktop app.

Currently my app is one window, with the main window entirely taken up by a console object, with is just a plain text edit, like this:

```
setCentralWidget(console);
```

Which of course takes up the entire window. So I added a frame using the UI editor, frame_2. How do I get the console to appear inside the frame, instead of taking up the whole window?

Comment: UI editor sets central widget itself. If you just want to get what you see in Designer, do not call `setCentralWidget`. But make sure that you've added a layout to the central widget (and the frame and all other containers you have in the form).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-layouts.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html

Your central widget is just `QWidget`, and then it needs a layout.  You drag a layout into it, and there are some buttons across the top of Qt Designer for turning on and off the layout.

When `setupUi` is called, it already does the `setCentralWidget` call for you.  If you call it yourself you lose all you gained from using Qt Designer.

```
ui->setupUi(this);
```

If you are using Qt Designer, you should not edit any generated files.  If you edit the .ui file again, it may generate the ui_.h file for you again and fix the problem.

Here is an example of the generated file ui_mainwindow.h:

```
/********************************************************************************
** Form generated from reading UI file 'mainwindow.ui'
**
** Created: Wed Jul 10 15:48:32 2013
**      by: Qt User Interface Compiler version 4.8.4
**
** WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost when recompiling UI file!
********************************************************************************/

#ifndef UI_MAINWINDOW_H
#define UI_MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtGui/QAction>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtGui/QHeaderView>
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui/QMenuBar>
#include <QtGui/QStatusBar>
#include <QtGui/QToolBar>
#include <QtGui/QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_MainWindow
{
public:
    QMenuBar *menuBar;
    QToolBar *mainToolBar;
    QWidget *centralWidget;
    QStatusBar *statusBar;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        if (MainWindow->objectName().isEmpty())
            MainWindow->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("MainWindow"));
        MainWindow->resize(400, 300);
        menuBar = new QMenuBar(MainWindow);
        menuBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menuBar"));
        MainWindow->setMenuBar(menuBar);
        mainToolBar = new QToolBar(MainWindow);
        mainToolBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("mainToolBar"));
        MainWindow->addToolBar(mainToolBar);
        centralWidget = new QWidget(MainWindow);
        centralWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("centralWidget"));
        // !!!!! NOTE !!!!! setCentralWidget gets called
        MainWindow->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
        statusBar = new QStatusBar(MainWindow);
        statusBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("statusBar"));
        MainWindow->setStatusBar(statusBar);

        retranslateUi(MainWindow);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainWindow);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
    {
        MainWindow->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow: public Ui_MainWindow {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_MAINWINDOW_H
```

I also rambled about using Layouts on a previous post:

[Add QRadioButton into QWidget without layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047861/add-qradiobutton-into-qwidget-without-layout/17051882#17051882)

Hope that helps.

Comment: so do I do something like:
   
iu->frame_2->addConsole? What do I put in the place of "addConsole"?

Comment: Create a member variable in mainwindow.h like this: `Console * m_console;` and then after `ui->setupUi(this);` in MainWindow's constructor, put `m_console = new Console();` `ui->frame_2->addWidget(m_console);`